# How i put this code into a TabView?

Tags: android

i have this code in a TabView class:

```
package jungle.timer;


import com.example.jungletimer.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



public class JungleTimers extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.jungle_timers, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
}
```

But i want to put **this code(↓↓↓)** into the **other (↑↑↑)** and i get errors, obviously, because i dont know how to put both codes together.
PD: i am newbie D:

https://github.com/Hersix/Codigos/blob/master/Code%20app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package jungle.timer;


import com.example.jungletimer.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



public class JungleTimers extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.jungle_timers, container, false);

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

                final TextView Texto = (TextView)rootView. findViewById(R.id.textView1);


                ImageView Start = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                Start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

                                     @Override
                                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                         Texto.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                                     }

                                     @Override
                                        public void onFinish() {
                                         Texto.setText("");
                                     }
                                  }.start();
                        }});

    return rootView;
}
}
```

Something like this?

Comment: So much better, but 1 thing, i get 3 errors, in setRequestedOrientation, and 2 of findViewById 
In everyone of these errors appear: Create Method " findViewById " or "setRequestedOrientation"

Comment: and do a getActivity().setRequestedOrientation

Comment: Continues with errors D:
I am deleting (at)Override words, because eclipse says me, maybe is for this ?

Comment: what do you mean with "do a getActivity().setRequestedOrientation" ?

Comment: the 3 that i said before (sorry for my english :D)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43088/discussion-between-user2511882-and-fabian-montossi)

Comment: Not a problem. Cheers